# reversing DC motor rotation using TWO limit Switches Problem !! need help

Tags: arduino-uno

I'd like to write a code for reversing DC motor rotation direction as follows:

1. Start the motor rotation clockwise (CW).
2. When reach Limit Switch (CW) → motor will stop for 5 sec.
3. after 5 sec. of stopping → the motor will rotate in counter clockwise direction(CCW).
4. When reach Limit Switch (CCW) → motor will stop for 5 sec.

and repeat point 1, 2, 3 and 4...

Actually I wrote a code for reversing the motor direction using **two** limit switches and it is working good. But when I added delay the motor did not stop using the limit Switches and continue to rotate... 
If any one can help...
Here is my code for reversing the direction with out delay 5 sec. My limit SWs are connected on Normal Open.

```c++
int sw1, sw2, sw3;
const int LM1 = 0;
const int LM2 = 1;
const int LM3 = 6;
const int CW = 10;
const int CCW = 9;
const int Buzzer = 7;


void setup() {
  pinMode(LM1, INPUT);
  pinMode(LM2, INPUT);
  pinMode(LM3, INPUT);
  pinMode(CW, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(CCW, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
  sw3 = digitalRead(LM3);
  sw1 = digitalRead(LM1);
  sw2 = digitalRead(LM2);

  if (sw1 == LOW && sw2 == HIGH) {
    do {
      digitalWrite(Buzzer, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(CW, HIGH);// change the direction of rotation (DOWN Movement)
      digitalWrite(CCW, LOW);

      sw2 = digitalRead(LM2);
    } while (sw2 == HIGH);
  }
  else if (sw1 == HIGH && sw2 == LOW) {
    do {
      digitalWrite(Buzzer, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(CW, LOW);// change the direction of rotation (UP Movement)
      digitalWrite(CCW, HIGH);

      sw1= digitalRead(LM1);
    } while (sw1 == HIGH);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally you use state machine for this kind of programming: you have a
`state` variable that remembers what you are doing, and depending on the
current state you decide what to do next. Below is an example with two
states. I have embedded a few assumptions about the wiring of your motor
and your switches, which may be wrong, so you have to check the code.

```cpp
void loop() {
    static enum {MOVING_CW, MOVING_CCW} state;

    switch (state) {
    case MOVING_CW:
        if (digitalRead(LM2) == LOW) {  // hit switch
            digitalWrite(CW, LOW);      // stop
            delay(5000);
            digitalWrite(CCW, HIGH);    // restart
            state = MOVING_CCW;
        }
        break;
    case MOVING_CCW:
        if (digitalRead(LM1) == LOW) {  // hit switch
            digitalWrite(CCW, LOW);     // stop
            delay(5000);
            digitalWrite(CW, HIGH);     // restart
            state = MOVING_CW;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

This will start in the `MOVING_CW` state, but you have to actually start
the movement in `setup()`. It has the drawback of having long delay()s in
the loop, which is undesirable if you have other tasks to perform. These
delays can be removed by “remembering” that you are waiting as two extra
states:

```cpp
void loop() {
    static enum {MOVING_CW, MOVING_CCW, STOPPED_CW, STOPPED_CCW} state;
    static unsigned long time_stopped;
    unsigned long now = millis();

    switch (state) {
    case MOVING_CW:
        if (digitalRead(LM2) == LOW) {  // hit switch
            digitalWrite(CW, LOW);      // stop
            state = STOPPED_CW;
            time_stopped = now;
        }
        break;
    case MOVING_CCW:
        if (digitalRead(LM1) == LOW) {  // hit switch
            digitalWrite(CCW, LOW);     // stop
            state = STOPPED_CCW;
            time_stopped = now;
        }
        break;
    case STOPPED_CW:
        if (now - time_stopped >= 5000) {
            digitalWrite(CCW, HIGH);    // restart
            state = MOVING_CCW;
        }
        break;
    case STOPPED_CCW:
        if (now - time_stopped >= 5000) {
            digitalWrite(CW, HIGH);     // restart
            state = MOVING_CW;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the code with the 5 second delay is more usefull. Because you are telling us the code you now deliver is supposed to work?

Probably using delay(5000) will work?

Comment: I added delay (5000); at the end of my code -- > Doesn't work also I tried to add delay at the start of my code ---> Doesn't work

Comment: You will have to make another state (idle). Here you will have to put the commands low, this way the motor will actually stop. Then you can add the delay to it, so the motor will stop for the 5 second duration.

Comment: kindly give me idea or example about this issue

Comment: Motor CW > Motor idle > Motor CCW > Motor idle > Motor CW…..
Every change in limit switching should change the state of the motor.
In your program now it is: Motor CW > Motor CCW > Motor CW…
Are you able to put the motor on or off with program code? 
Or are you only able to change its direction? If so, would writing both CW and CCW LOW deliver any problems?